# JQuery Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ,

Tags: jquery, insertafter

I'm trying to simply add a comma after each element in a list.

```
$('#tag_cloud-2 div.tagcloud a').each(function(){
  console.log($(this));
  $(", ").after($(this));
});
```

The console spits out the  tags so I know it is finding them. I've tried insertAfter as well, but with no luck. This seams like it should be such a simple thing to do!! Thanks for pointing out what I'm missing.

Comment: `", "` is interpreted as selector and as such it is invalid. Also your usage of `.after()` is just wrong. See: http://api.jquery.com/after/

Comment: i think you mean `$(this).after(',');`

Comment: Where are you trying to write this to? Should the comma separated list be sent to the console or some thing?

Comment: thanks so much. I totally misread that documentation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$(', ')` is treated as selector(invalid), because it can't create text node with containing string.

But

`$("<span>, </span>").after($(this));` will work because of a valid markup.

Try:

```
$(this).after(', ');
```

**OR**

```
$(this).append(', ');
```

**OR**

```
$(this).text(function(i, oldText) {
  return oldText + ', ';
})
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's [$()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) function doesn't quite work like that. Calling it on a non-markup string does not create a text node containing that string.

You can invert your logic, start from `$(this)`, then call [after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/), though:

```
$(this).after(", ");
```

Because `after()` creates a new text node if one of its arguments is a non-markup string.